# for statement with a sorted function-how it works

Tags: python

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
word = input("Provide a word to search for vowels: ")

found = {}

for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        found.setdefault(letter, 0)
        found[letter] += 1

for k, v in sorted(found.items()):
    print(k, 'was found', v, 'time(s).')
```

I’m a beginner in Python and in programming in general. With the input “good” the output “o” was found 2 time(s). The code works fine, however the last block of code confuses me. The variable k produces the letter o and the variable v produces the number 2. This is the key set from the dictionary. How is the code interpreted to produce this output?

Comment: Is it the syntax of the for loop that confuses you, or the way how the actual values end up in the dictionary?

Comment: Why not try `print(sorted(found.items()))` to see what you are iterating over? Then you might be able to answer your own question. Also -- look into `Counter` in the `collections` module for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have to understand what the `.items()` dictionary method returns. You can google that.. Forget about the `sorted()`; it just re-arranges the data.

Comment: My advice to you would be to rewrite the code and use the `.count(x)` method applied to the input string. Makes your life easier.

Comment: Yes it is clearer to me now. As many have stated and advised further reading about the dictionaries method called “items” which returns a sequence of tuples with a key-pair. These key pair are useful in the iteration in a  for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) produces a sorted list from it's input. That input here is the [`found.items()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), which itself is an iterable of tuples containing `(key, value)` pairs from the dictionary. Since tuples are ordered lexicographically (comparing first their first elements, then if equal, the second elements, etc.) you end up with a list of `(key, value)` pairs sorted in alphabetical order.

You can try this out yourself in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
>>> word = 'good'
>>> found = {}
>>> for letter in word:
...     if letter in vowels:
...         found.setdefault(letter, 0)
...         found[letter] += 1
...
0
1
>>> found
{'o': 2}
>>> list(found.items())
[('o', 2)]
>>> sorted(found.items())
[('o', 2)]
```

Of course, since `good` only contains **one** unique vowel, `o`, there is little to sort by.  A sorted list with just one `(key, value)` pair won't show any change in order.

If you tried with a more complex word, like `ultrarevolutionaries`, you'd get a much more interesting result:

```
>>> word = 'ultrarevolutionaries'
>>> found = {}
>>> for letter in word:
...     if letter in vowels:
...         found.setdefault(letter, 0)
...         found[letter] += 1
...
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
>>> list(found.items())
[('u', 2), ('a', 2), ('e', 2), ('o', 2), ('i', 2)]
>>> sorted(found.items())
[('a', 2), ('e', 2), ('i', 2), ('o', 2), ('u', 2)]
```

The items are out of order first, `u`, `a`, `e`, `o`, `i` is not in alphabetical order. `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` on the other hand *is*.

Comment: Yes it is clearer to me now. As many have stated and advised further reading about the dictionaries method called “items” which returns a sequence of tuples with a key-pair. These key pair are useful in the iteration in a  for loop.